# What is the difference between these MPMediaQuery results?

Tags: ios, swift, mpmediaquery

What is the difference in the results between these two queries:

```
let myQuery:MPMediaQuery = MPMediaQuery.songsQuery()
myQuery.groupingType = MPMediaGrouping.Album
```

and

```
let myQuery:MPMediaQuery = MPMediaQuery.albumsQuery()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of 6th version, XCode has brilliant playgrounds functionality. Consider following code in Playground:

```
let myQuery1:MPMediaQuery = MPMediaQuery.songsQuery()
myQuery1.groupingType = MPMediaGrouping.Album

let myQuery2:MPMediaQuery = MPMediaQuery.albumsQuery()

myQuery1 == myQuery2
```

The latter comparison resolves to "true", which means, that both above queries are effectively identical.

[Playground screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4ysie4g646yzhkk/Screenshot%202016-03-16%2022.51.08.png?dl=0)

Comment: Thanks! I will try Playgrounds too.